# R - Convert a bipartite edgelist to a unipartite adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, social-networking

I have a bipartite edgelist that I would like to convert into a unipartite graph of just the 'from' nodes. I need to do this in a sparse matrix because of the size. Unfortunately, this means that easier solutions such as using `bipartite.projection(graph)` freezes everything. My data looks like:

```
To          From     Weight
A1          B2       1
A1          B3       1
A2          B2       1
A3          B3       1
A3          B4       1
A4          B2       1
A4          B3       1
```

Using the Matrix package, I've created a sparse matrix with the correct dimensions, but for some reason only the diagonal is populated. For the sparse matrix I used:

```
myMat <- sparseMatrix(as.integer(as.factor(df$from), 
                      as.integer(as.factor(df$from),
                      x = df$weight,
                      dimnames = list(levels(as.factor(df$from)),
                                      levels(as.factor(df$from))
                                     ) 
                      )
```

returns:

```
   B2  B3  B4
B2  2  .   .
B3  .  2   .
B4  .  .   1
```

The diagonal summed the weight, but the rest of the matrix is empty where I was expecting it to have filled with the summed weight as well.

What I'd like is:

```
   B2  B3  B4
B2  .  2   .
B3  2  .   1
B4  .  1   .
```

As this is a matrix of one side of the bipartite graph with the `matrix[i,j]` representing the count of `df$to` values connecting any two `df$from` values. This would then be the weight I would give to edges in any network graph.

Answer (score 0):

What about `as_adjacency_matrix` which returns sparse?

```
library(igraph)
df <- read.table(textConnection("
To          From     Weight
A1          B2       1
A1          B3       1
A2          B2       1
A3          B3       1
A3          B4       1"), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

g <- graph.data.frame(df[,1:2])
V(g)$type <- V(g)$name %in% df[,1]

is.bipartite(g)
as_adjacency_matrix(g)
```

Comment: That almost works, but it returns the sparse matrix for the bipartite graph, I'd like to reduce the graph to just the 'from' nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using some matrix algebra rather than a defined function to get my result. By changing around the `sparseMatrix` call just a tiny bit and then multiplying by the transpose I got the matrix I was looking for

```
myMat <- sparseMatrix(as.integer(as.factor(df$from), 
                  as.integer(as.factor(df$to),
                  x = 1,
                  dimnames = list(levels(as.factor(df$from)),
                                  levels(as.factor(df$to))
                                 ) 
                  )

finalMat <- myMat %*% t(myMat)
```